# Smooth transition

Tags: css, angular

I have an application written in Angular. Here comes the code for the template and the TS files:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primay" (click)="changeColumnsSize()"> change column sizes</button>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="leftColumn" class="col-sm-{{leftColumnSize}}" style="background-color:lavender;">
      .col-sm-8     
    </div>
    <div id ="rightColumn" *ngIf="this.state===true" class="col-sm-{{rightColumnSize}}" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      .col-sm-4
    </div>
  </div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-box',
  templateUrl: './box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./box.component.css']
})
export class BoxComponent {

  leftColumnSize: number = 8;
  rightColumnSize: number = 4;
  colDifference: number = 2;
  state: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  changeColumnsSize(){
    if (this.state===false)
      this.state = true;
    else
      this.state = false;

    if(this.state===true) {
      this.leftColumnSize-=this.colDifference;
      this.rightColumnSize+=this.colDifference;
    }
    else if (this.state===false) {
      this.leftColumnSize+=this.colDifference;
      this.rightColumnSize-=this.colDifference;
    }
  }
}
```

By clicking the button, the size of `leftColumnSize` reduces to 8 and `rightColumn` renders with size 4. By clicking it again, `leftColumnSize`resets and `rightColumn` gets removed.
But I want this to happen in a smooth way, kind of transition or animation.
Could you please help me with writing the relevant CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS transition property:

For example:

```
.col-sm-8 {
  width: 60%;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  width: 40%;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}

.col-sm-2 {
  width: 20%;
  transition: width .5s ease;
}
```

Also you can optimize it by creating general .transition class for animated elements.

```
.transition {transition: width .5s ease;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular animations are defined in the @Component metadata as seen here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    // animation definitions here
  ]
})
```

You then need to define triggers which are added to the html elements that you want to animate. For example:

```
animations: [
  trigger('heroState', [
    state('inactive', style({
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
      transform: 'scale(1)'
    })),
    state('active',   style({
      backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
      transform: 'scale(1.1)'
    })),
    transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
    transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
  ])
]
```

You then attach these animations to the html element using the `[@triggerName]` syntax as seen here:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
        [@heroState]="hero.state"
        (click)="hero.toggleState()">
      {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

You should read up on Angular animations here:

https://angular.io/guide/animations

This information should get you going in the right direction. I would try to take the time to write out your exact answer, but you know the saying, give a man a fish and he will not be hungry for a day, teach him how to fish and he will not be hungry for a lifetime.

I wish you the best of luck!

Happy learning!!